# I want to pass immutable Java objects as a reference, is there an alternative to AtomicReferences or Array or List?

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons

Let's say I want a method to modify 2 Strings (or any other immutable class), I can't return a single object. So I can pass a List, String[] or 2 AtomicReference objects. Each of these has downsides. Lists and arrays don't allow naming of each of the parameters, and we're relying on the order of the elements to ensure the right Strings are set. AtomicReference is intended atomic updates so it does way more than what I need it to do. I simply need something like this:

```
public class Reference <T> {
    private T value;
    public T get() {
        return value;
    }

    public void set(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I would think a class like this is available in some Apache library or Spring library, but I couldn't find anything like this. I would think this is a pretty basic need for many developers, so is it in some 3rd party library that I'm not aware of?

This mostly applies to the case of 2 or 3 objects. When there are >3 immutable objects, I might create a new class just to hold these references.

I'm also aware of Apache Pair and Triple, but they have the same issue as List, where I can't name the parameters.

Comment: Asking for libraries, APIs, ... is off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "named tuples" to be immutable, the best fit for your requirements is a Java 14+ `record` class.  Essentially, it is a lightweight class that is roughly analogous to a C / C++ `struct` .... but immutable;

When you *need* the "named tuples" to be mutable (or if Java 14+ is not an option for you yet), there two alternatives:

- If the "field" names are dynamic, then you can use a `Map`.  Any `Map` implementation will do.  There are problems with this:

  - You must use `m.get(name)` and `m.put(name, value)` syntax.
  - The compiler cannot check that you are using the correct `name` strings.
  - The values all need to be the same type, or have the same base type.  If the "fields" have different types, you will need to use type-casting; e.g. from `Object` to the expected type.
- If the "field" names are static (i.e. you want to be able to refer to them as Java identifiers, the only alternative is to declare a conventional class.  It could be an "unencapsulated" class; e.g.

  ```
  public class Things {
      public Type1 thing1;
      public Type2 thing2;
  }
  ```

  The fields could be declared as `final` and then you will need to
  declare a constructor.

  While it is good style to have getters, setters and a constructor, the Java language doesn't force you to do declare and/or use them.  You just need to understand the consequences of ignoring encapsulation.  (And be able to cope with the negative code reviews ...)

For what it is worth, you **cannot** design a library class where the names of your fields are regular parameters or type parameters.  (Or at least, not in a way that can be *used* by conventional Java code; e.g. using `x.name` or `x.getName()`.)  That's why you can't find one!